# Executing multiple commands in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am creating a hot folder. The file names coming in to the hot folder will end with either *.pdf.tif (incorrect) or *.pdf.k.tif (correct). If the file comes in using the naming convention *.pdf.k.tif, I want to just move it to the destination folder. If the file comes in using the *.pdf.tif naming convention I want to rename it to the *.pdf.k.tif naming convention and then move it to the destination folder. Also note the source and destination folder is the same regardless of naming convention.

The script below works to solve both things individually. If the file is named correctly, it moves to the destination. If the file is named incorrectly, the script renames it correctly but it does not move the file after it is renamed.

How can I make it so when the file is renamed, it still moves?

```
$where_to_move_folder = "C:\Users\jonsl\Desktop\Jobs-In"
$createdAction = 
{
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

Dir $folder_to_watch *.tif | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace ".pdf.tif",".pdf.k.tif"};
Move-Item -path $($folder_to_watch + "\" + $name) -destination $where_to_move_folder -force

}

$filter = '*.tif'
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher 
$fsw.Path = $folder_to_watch
$fsw.Filter = $filter 
$fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$fsw.NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action $createdAction

$fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
```

Comment: Please note I left out the first line. It should have been: 

$folder_to_watch = "C:\Users\jonsl\Desktop\LANG"

Comment: `dir *.tif |rename-item -passthru |move-item`

Comment: Thank you Mathias. Should the line then look like the following? I still get the rename but not the move. Dir $folder_to_watch *.tif | rename-item -newname{  $_.name  -replace ".pdf.tif",".pdf.k.tif"} -PassThru | Move-Item -path $($folder_to_watch + "\" + $name) -destination $where_to_move_folder -force

Comment: Remove the -path bit from move-item

Comment: That worked great thank you Mathias. One thing - I had the watch folder set to also include subdirectories. That was working. When I add in your modifications, the subdirectories aren't watched. Any ideas there? For others that might read this the line that did the trick looks like  Dir $folder_to_watch *.tif | rename-item -newname{  $_.name  -replace ".pdf.tif",".pdf.k.tif"} -PassThru | Move-Item -destination $where_to_move_folder -force

Comment: It looks like I got that part. I added the -recurse after dir. It now looks like Dir $folder_to_watch *.tif -recurse | rename-item -newname{  $_.name  -replace ".pdf.tif",".pdf.k.tif"} -PassThru | Move-Item -destination $where_to_move_folder -force